# JQuery Variable Declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every thing goes fine but when i declaring Variable **answeredQ+i** Getting Error

```
var count = 5;
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    var className = '.myclass'+i;
    var answeredQ+i = $(className).map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
}
```

Comment: use eval ......

Comment: Then how To use it?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: What you intent to use with the variable?

Comment: @Dev Why do you need a variable with the name `answeredQ1`, `answeredQ2`, ... ?

Comment: @Dev you need to tell us the reason you are choosing to have dynamic variable, We might be able to help you with better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var count = 5;
var answered = {};
for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    var className = '.myclass'+i;
    answered['Q' + i] = $(className).map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
}
```

Now you can use `answered.Q1` or `answered['Q1']` to access first variable, Q2 for 2nd variable, etc.

What you're trying to achieve is known as 'Variable variable'. Many programming languages supports it, but in Javascript there is no straightforward answer, so you have to use an array or object to contain the new variables.

Read about 'variable variable' for more details: ["Variable" variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

use `window['answeredQ'+i]` but you are probably better assigning the answer to an array, rather than directly to the global scope.

```js
var count = 5;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var className = '.myclass' + i;
  window['answeredQ' + i] = $(className).map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get();
}
```

Comment: This `window['answeredQ'+i]` will create the variable in global scope, right?

Comment: Yes, as said it's not ideal.

Comment: how to use this  __window['answeredQ'+i]__ outside for loop?

Comment: it's the same as any variable declared in the global scope (outside of a function) `answeredQ0` or `window.answeredQ0` or `window['answeredQ0']`

Answer (score 0):

As this variable declaration is invalid, you can use an `object` to hold all this dynamic keys and use the same outside the `for` loop as below.

```js
var count = 5;
var answers = {};

for(var i=0;i<count;i++){
    var className = '.myclass'+i;
    answers['answeredQ' + i] = $(className).map(function(){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();
}

console.log(answers);

Object.keys(answers).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(key + ': ');
  console.log(answers[key]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```